# Passing List of KeyValuePairs to LINQ query and selecting the Value for the Key that matches the entity's Id

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, .net-5

What is the best way to solve this?

**TL;DR version:**

Using LINQ and EntityFramework I am trying to pass in a `List` of `KeyValuePair`s to a LINQ query, then for each entity who's ID matches any Key in the list, selecting a new column with that key's value.

So if my `KeyValuePair`s are

```
List<KeyValuePair(int, long)> keyValuePairs = new() 
{
    new(1, 10),
    new(2, 20),
    new(3, 30)
}
```

where the key is an `EmployeeId` and the value is a `CompanyId`,

and I'm querying an Employees table, with two columns, `Id` and `Name`,

and my `EmployeeModel` class is

```
public int Id;
public int Name;
public long CompanyId;
```

I want to do something like this:

```
var keys = keyValuePairs.Select(x => x.Key);

IQueryable<EmployeeModel> EmployeeModels = Db.Employees
    .Where(e => keys.Contains(p.Id))
    .Select(e => new EmployeeModel 
    {
        Id = e.Id,
        Name = e.Name,
        CompanyId = keyValuePairs.Where(x => x.Key == e.Id).Select(x => x.Value).First()
    });
```

Currently I get this exception:

> The LINQ expression 'x' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

I want to avoid loading this into memory because the results could potentially be hundreds of thousands. In addition, I need to pass the result into a method that requires an IQueryable

**More context for understanding what I'm trying to do (and maybe someone can see if this is an x-y problem):**

I have two Databases
Database A has a Table called Companies and a join table called CompanyEmployees

Database B has a Table called Employees
The Employee table has a column for Employee Id, but no column for Company Id

My `EmployeeModel` class however, has a prop for the `CompanyId` of the company to which the employee belongs.
I'm trying to load a list of employees, and selecting a `EmployeeModel` which includes the `CompanyId`

The way I'm trying to accomplish that is loading into memory a List of `KeyValuePair`s where the `Key = CustomerEmployee.EmployeeId` and the `Value = CustomerEmployee.CustomerId` and then using that List to Query the other Db.
(I don't see any alternative to loading the List of `KeyValuePair`s into memory, even though I'd obviously rather not)

Comment: You can't. EF Core has strict limitations about local collection - only `Contains`. Here you need JOIN to VALUES table, which is not supported.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv What other options do I have for getting the data that I need then?

Comment: Probably you have to specify Database Provider which you are using. And tell me, databases are located on the same server?

Comment: Yes I believe so.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work to me if you put `AsEnumerable` after the `Where` so that only the matching data is copied over, as long as `keyValuePairs` is not a very long list (there are limitations to the SQL query size).

Answer (score 0):

Also you probably have a problem with this part:

```
CompanyId = keyValuePairs.Where(x => x.Key == e.Id).Select(x => x.Value)
```

As CompanyId is a long, and the result of your Linq expression is a IEnumerable.
If you're sure you have a result and only one, then you may use:

```
CompanyId = keyValuePairs.Where(x => x.Key == e.Id).Select(x => x.Value).First()
```

Comment: Ah, true, thats a typo. The code I was trying does use `First()` I edited the question